# How to determine the user and group of a daemon in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, user-accounts, root

How can I check the user and group for the `nginx` daemon in Ubuntu?

Or what's the syntax to find the user and group for a daemon running in Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You seem to have found out the user and group for the nginx daemon just fine.

Comment: how to find the user and group for the nginx deamon

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Simply use `ps` while it is running:

```
oliver@ubuntuServer:~$ ps aux|grep nginx|grep -v grep
root     17119  0.0  0.1  57492  1156 ?        Ss   14:22   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data 17120  0.0  0.1  57804  1572 ?        S    14:22   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 17121  0.0  0.1  57804  1572 ?        S    14:22   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 17122  0.0  0.1  57804  1572 ?        S    14:22   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 17123  0.0  0.1  57804  1572 ?        S    14:22   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

As you can see in the first column, the initial nginx master process is started with the `root` user account. This process will spawn the workers under the `www-data` user account. This would be the one you care about.

If `nginx` isn't running, you can just as well pull the information from the configuration file like so:

```
oliver@ubuntuServer:~$ grep user /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user www-data;
```

Comment: So if I want to restart nginx in this case, I need to do it with `root` user or `www-data` user? Sometimes I get a `open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)`...

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger You should probably use `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: Instead of `grep nginx | grep -v grep`, I like to do `grep [n]ginx`, which keeps  it from matching its own process listing. Just a fun tip.

Answer (score 21):

To answer the "and group" part of the question for the running process, use the supgrp (names of supplementary groups) format specifier too. Try:

```
 ps -eo pid,comm,euser,supgrp | grep nginx
```

Answer (score 2):

I always do 'ps aux | grep whatever' but I'm not an admin.  If the above is right and 'ps' tells you what you need to know, do that.  Then you have to do 'kill ###' not 'kill name' (### meaning eg 17119 from above).  Assuming you want to kill it.  It's daemon, not deamon, btw.

Answer (score 1):

`ps -eo user,comm | grep nginx` will give you the user who running `nginx`.

`top` or `htop` can be used to find the user of a process, too.

then you could find the group of a user use: `groups USERNAME`

Comment: how to delete the userroot     nginx
www-data nginx
www-data nginx
www-data nginx
www-data nginx

Comment: why you want to delete user `www-data`? running web server daemon with this user is expected result. ok, you can delete it uses `userdel` command.

Comment: Note, however, that effective and supplementary groups of a running process may not match these of user account for various reasons. Given `CAP_SETGID` capability (which root usually has), process can modify both effective GID and supplementary group list.  Because of this, `ps` solution is better.